# Processing a sequence of pairs

Tags: expl3, xparse

I want to process a list of pairs like this:

```
{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}}
```

where the first items in each pairs are distinct.

So, for each pair of those `{ai,bi}` I would need the following data:

```
{a1,a2,a3,...,an} % does not contain ai
ai
bi
```

Then I call a macro with these

```
\foo{ai}{a1 \\ a2 \\ ... \\ an}{bi}
```

Ideally, it should work with more than just pairs, i.e. `{{a1,b1,c1,d1},...}`

Here's what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4mm,multi=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { g_data_#1_seq }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\removefromlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gremove_all:cx { g_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\purgelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:c { g_data_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_use:cnnn { g_data_#1_seq } { ~\\ } { ~\\ } { ~\\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gremove_all:cn {cx}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

And I have a macro that will use these data combinations:

```
\newcommand{\playcardfamily}[2]{{
    \foreach \thiscard in {#2}{
        \createlist{relatives}{#2}
        \removefromlist{relatives}{\thiscard}
        % Needs to process to get the title in \thistitle and picture in
        % \thispicture. relatives should contain only the titles.
        \playcard{#1}{\thistitle}{\printlist{relatives}}{\thispicture}
    }
}}
```

In the document I have

```
\begin{document}
    \playcardfamily{Family}{{Member1,picture1.png},{Member2,picture2.png},{Member3,picture3.png}}
\end{document}
```

To clarify, what I want to get from `\playcardfamily{...}` here is:

```
\playcard{Family}{Member1}{Member2 \\ Member3}{picture1.png}
\playcard{Family}{Member2}{Member1 \\ Member3}{picture2.png}
\playcard{Family}{Member3}{Member1 \\ Member2}{picture3.png}
```

I'm open to any hints and ideas on how to solve this.

## Solution

By a slight modification of egreg's solution I managed to produce the cards I needed
[image: Cards]

[Full code](https://github.com/initysteppa/playingcards)

Comment: What's `bi`? To handle a complete sequence list without knowing the count, you can use `seq_map_inline`.

Comment: Can we assume that the first items in each pair are distinct?

Comment: Yes we can, but the other items might not be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd propose defining, for each family, a sequence containing its members and a property list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createfamily}{ m m }
 {
  \magnus_createfamily:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\playcardfamily}{ m }
 {
  \magnus_playcardfamily:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_magnus_tempa_seq
\seq_new:N \l_magnus_tempb_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \magnus_createfamily:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }
  \prop_new:c { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _prop }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \magnus_populate:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \magnus_populate:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_magnus_tempa_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_gput_right:cx
   { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }
   { \seq_item:Nn \l_magnus_tempa_seq { 1 } }
  \prop_gput:cxx
   { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _prop }
   { \seq_item:Nn \l_magnus_tempa_seq { 1 } }
   { \seq_item:Nn \l_magnus_tempa_seq { 2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \magnus_playcardfamily:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_eq:Nc \l_magnus_tempa_seq { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }
   {
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l_magnus_tempb_seq \l_magnus_tempa_seq
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l_magnus_tempb_seq { ##1 }
    \magnus_playcard:nnxx
     { #1 }
     { ##1 }
     { \seq_use:Nn \l_magnus_tempb_seq { \\ } }
     { \prop_get:cn { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _prop } { ##1 } }
   }
 }

% This should do something more useful, probably ;-)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \magnus_playcard:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \tl_show:n { \#1~is~#1,~\#2~is~#2,~\#3~is~#3,~\#4~is~#4 }
 }    

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \magnus_playcard:nnnn { nnxx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\createfamily{Family}
 {
  {Member1,picture1.png},
  {Member2,picture2.png},
  {Member3,picture3.png}
 }

\playcardfamily{Family}

\stop
```

The output I get on the terminal is

```
> \#1 is Family, \#2 is Member1, \#3 is Member2\\Member3, \#4 is picture1.png.
<recently read> }

l.71 \playcardfamily{Family}

?
> \#1 is Family, \#2 is Member2, \#3 is Member1\\Member3, \#4 is picture2.png.
<recently read> }

l.71 \playcardfamily{Family}

?
> \#1 is Family, \#2 is Member3, \#3 is Member1\\Member2, \#4 is picture3.png.
<recently read> }

l.71 \playcardfamily{Family}

?
```

Comment: I'm curious: is there a reason you converted the token lists to strings before building a csname instead of using them directly (e.g. `\seq_new:c { g_magnus_family_ #1 _seq }` instead of `\seq_new:c { g_magnus_family_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }`)?

Comment: @cgnieder `\createfamily{Müller}{...}`

Comment: @cgnieder Condidering Magnus's name seems typical of some Nordic country, family names with strange letters such as ø or ü are expected.